# How to code public key encryption logic in php given sample java logic?

Tags: java, php, laravel, encryption, rsa

I have a project of coding encryption logic using public key in php.
Given following sample Java code, how do you code it in php?
The specification document says to encrypt source with RSA(2048 bit).

```
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.json.JSONObject;

//some other codes...

String PUBLIC_KEY = "";
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
String data = new JSONObject(map).toString();

//generating public key object
byte[] buffer = Base64.decodeBase64(PUBLIC_KEY.getBytes());
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(buffer);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
//encryption data
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte[] encryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
//base 64
String encrypted = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedByte, Base64.DEFAULT);
return encrypted;
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code writing service - show your attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solved php conversion myself by using module phpseclib\Crypt\RSA

```
    $token = file_get_contents($path);
    $base64_decoded = base64_decode($token);
    $pubKey = new RSA();
    $pubKey->setEncryptionMode(RSA::ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
    $pubKey->loadKey($base64_decoded);
    $crypted = $pubKey->encrypt($json);
    return base64_encode($crypted);
```